# Making a button?

Tags: python

So I have this simple menu in python:

```
1 - x
2 - y
3 - z
what you gonna do?
```

I want to ask user to press a number to choose the option but I can't figure it out, instead of making user write the option and pressing enter, I want the user to press number and do the option!
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should look into one of the graphical libraries: `PyQt` for example, but there are a lot of them. And see if you can follow a tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: Try Tkinter module it is a built in module so it comes with python. Start Here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button is a "visual" component, and thus requires a library of some sort to develop with relative ease. As Neftas mentions, there are a number of these libraries out there for free, one being PyQt.

Checkout this thread for more:[What Python GUI APIs Are Out There?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93930/what-python-gui-apis-are-out-there)